# How can I efficiently find out if a user is a member of a group using the Okta API?

Tags: okta

I can view OKTA users in a group (`/groups/{groupid}/users`), and I can grab all groups belonging to a user (`/users/{userid}/groups`).

But both of those can return a lot of data and the latency is too high because of it. Can I specify which fields to return in the second call above?

How can I do a simple check if a user is a member of a group?

Okta Expression Language contains group functions such as `isMemberOfGroup`, but there is no examples or explanation of how to use that as part of an API call. I tried using it with the filter querystring, but no go.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot as the Okta API does not currently offer an isMemberOfGroup method. You'll have to use either of the 2 APIs you mentioned in your question, whichever is the most efficient in your specific case.